# Disable editing of cells in XamGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, infragistics, xamgrid

I am working on **XamGrid** binded with the ***DataTable***. I want to ***disable the editing of cells*** on a specific condition. I have created the behavior of the **XamGrid**.

Can suggest solution according to my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Try to define style with data triggers:

```
        <igWPF:XamDataGrid.Resources>

        ...
        <Style TargetType="CellValuePresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--one condition based trigger - condition is inside the cell data context-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataItem.ConditionA}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <!--multiple condition based trigger - condition is inside the cell data context-->
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataItem.ConditionA}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataItem.ConditionB}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        ...

    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.Resources>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use style of `CellValuePresenter`:

```
<Style x:Key="DisableForCTE" TargetType="{x:Type iDP:CellValuePresenter}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataItem.CTESubLocation}" Value="No">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>                        
         </DataTrigger>                    
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also if condition is predefined, `cells` can be disabled as column level:

```
 <iDP:Field Name="LatestEffectiveDate" Label="Latest Effective Date" >
 <iDP:Field.Settings>
     <iDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False">                                       
     </iDP:FieldSettings>
  </iDP:Field.Settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
 dataGrid.EditingSettings.AllowEditing = EditingType.None;
```